# Bash: Difference between > and >> operator?

Tags: unix, bash

I  don't know much about bash.

My instructor asked me to make a cat script and to observe the output and then tell what is the operator > and what is the difference between the operators > & >>.

I am unable to find any justifications. Could you help?

Comment: You could fiddle with temporary files to get the difference between >> and >.

Answer (score 105):

The `>` sign is used for redirecting the output of a program to something other than stdout (standard output, which is the terminal by default).

The `>>` appends to a file or creates the file if it doesn't exist.
The `>` overwrites the file if it exists or creates it if it doesn't exist.

In either case, the output of the program is stored in the file whose name is provided after the redirection operator.

**Examples:**
`$ ls > allmyfiles.txt` creates the file "allmyfiles.txt" and fills it with the directory listing from the ls command

`$ echo "End of directory listing" >> allmyfiles.txt` adds "End of directory listing" to the end of the file "allmyfiles.txt"

`$ > newzerobytefile` creates a new zero byte file with the name "newzerobytefile" or overwrites an existing file of the same name (making it zero bytes in size)

Comment: More IO redirection awesomeness: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: and `&>` ? I also see that around